# Ola Hallengren’s SQL Server Maintenance Solution using a different user

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I am looking at using Ola Hallengren’s SQL Server Maintenance Solution to create a backup plan.

However, I cannot figure out how to run the Agent Job (T-SQL script) as a different user as the current user does not have access to the network backup folder.

I have created a Credential and Proxy, but this only seems to be available for Agent Jobs running SSIS jobs. I have also tried setting the Job Owner as the domain user, but this did not work.

Comment: The SQL Agent is a Windows service running on the SQL Server, and you normally change the user with the [SQL Server Configuration Manager utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: This is already set as a domain account, but in this instance for this job I want to run it as a different user that has access to the backup device

Comment: If you go under Advanced tab for T-SQL steps, you should see a "Run as user" box.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Whatever initiates the backup, the interaction with the OS (i.e. your backup target) is going to be done by whatever account is running the SQL Server itself.

Comment: As @NateH mentions, try the Run as user" box. If that is empty, you can find answers here to populate a proxy account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112276/sql-agent-job-run-as-drop-down-list-is-empty

Comment: The user that runs the Agent job is irrelevant. It is the database engine that produces the log backup, regardless of who executes the BACKUP command. So you need to make sure that the SQL Server service account has appropriate permissions.

Comment: I've had luck with the (admittedly hacky) approach of making the Agent job have two steps. Step 1 used CmdExec to run a `net use ...` command to authenticate to the network destination. Step 2 did the `Backup Database...` part. Ugly, but it worked for us. Perhaps you can use that method.